# Why python is not following my sequence of print statement calls

Tags: python, os.walk

I am learning python and just tried out the os.walk() function.I am using python 3.4.4 (64-bit) on windows platform.According to my understanding python should execute my statements line by line.

In this code i have iterated over a directory.The directory structure is

[image: The directory structure is as shown]

I need to print all the files first followed by the directory names.The code written is:

```
import os
dir_path = r"D:\\python_os_walk_check"

for root,dirs,files in os.walk(dir_path):
    for file_name in files:
        print(file_name)
    for dir_name in dirs:
        print(dir_name)
```

The ouput printed is:

```
first_folder
second_folder
test1.txt
test2.txt
```

According to me the output should be:

```
test1.txt
test2.txt
first_folder
second_folder
```

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first get the contents of `dir_path`, which is only the two directories. The files are inside the directories, so you get to them later, in a second and third iteration of your loop. Add a `print(root)` as the first thing inside the loop and you'll see more clearly what's happening.

Comment: Ok i got it.i was assuming that a list of total iterated files would have been returned in the files variable.Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the names of files/directories and print them once your for loop completes.

```
import os
dir_path = "D:\\python_os_walk_check"

file_list = []
dir_list = []

for root,dirs,files in os.walk(dir_path):
    for file_name in files:
        file_list.append(file_name)
    for dir_name in dirs:
        dir_list.append(dir_name)

for x in file_list:
    print(x)

for i in dir_list:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Actually printing  wasn't my final aim, i wanted to understand what's going wrong in my understanding of the code above

Answer (score 0):

You might get a bit more like what you seem to want if you use the topdown parameter in `os.walk` like so:

```
import os
dir_path = r"C:\Python34\Tools\pynche"

for root,dirs,files in os.walk(dir_path, topdown=False):
    for file_name in files:
        print(file_name)
    for dir_name in dirs:
        print(dir_name)
```

Unfortunately I think this is only good for two-level folders.

As a more up-to-date solution you could consider the abilities offered in the `pathlib` module, Python 3 doc 11.1.

Comment: Oh yes,this could have been another way of obtaining the same output for 2 level-folder as said.

Comment: And, yes, I know.